# silent install of the application fails to install driver if VM Application is used while creating the Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I am trying to create the Azure VM and use the VM application to silently install the application. Link to the procedure is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/vm-applications-how-to.

Application fails to install the driver with the error 0x800b0109: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.
It looks like the driver can't be installed since some root CA is missing. And it can't be installed automatically since the user running silent install has no proper rights.

I tried to just create VM and then run silent install from the command prompt, and that works just fine.

Has anyone had problems like that and how was it solved?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce same in my environment I got the error like below.***

[image]

This error says root certificate, which is not trusted by the trust provider, as silently install is running sometimes root certificate is not installed automatically it may cause error on application installation.

To resolve this issue, try to download Microsoft Root [Certificate](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/microsoft-root-certificate-2011cer/4a6aca92-fa7b-40a2-959d-4c440f3ec91d)

Click **Start** ->**Run** , type **mmc** , and then click **OK**

Click File -> Add/Remove snap in like below:

[image]

Click on certificate -> Add :

[image]

Select -> computer name and finish it.

[image]

In *console1 MMC* you can see certificate -> Expand **Trusted Root Certification Authorities** , like below:

[image]

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/DSJc0Qg.png)]

***Once the Trusted Root Certification Authorities as imported I can able to install the application successfully***

[image]

---

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed response.  
However, I do not have problem with the root certificate once the VM is created and I am logged in. I that case I can run silent install and all is installed correctly.

Comment: I have problem with the "VM Application". I specify all the parameters for the Azure VM to be created. One of the parameters is the "VM Application". It specifies what application to install once the Azure creates the VM. This is some Azure process that runs the silent installation. Which fails since the root certificate is missing, and this process probably has not rights to install it. Note also that at this point VM is still not created and I do not have access to it.